# django using multiple SESSION ENGINE?

Tags: python, django

I want to use redis and encrypted_cookies (https://github.com/brightinteractive/django-encrypted-cookie-session/)
as a `SESSION_ENGINE` in my project `settings.py` file but how can I set both of them for my Django Application?

Is there actually any need to use encrypted cookies if I use redis?

`settings.py`

...

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'encrypted_cookies'
```

...

But according to the redis docs I also need to set

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"
```

see: https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/

Thank's in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for both of them.

The session engine is where you store the information of a client (like what items are in the shopping cart). You don't need to store that information in two places.

The encrypted cookies engine will store the information in a cookie, and Redis will store it on your server. The Redis engine will then give the client a cookie containing just an id that Redis can find when the client makes another request.